# DynamoDB ExclusiveStartKey Misuse?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was planning to use a Dynamo table as a sort of replication log, so I have a table that looks like this:

`+--------------+--------+--------+
| Sequence Num | Action | Thing  |
+--------------+--------+--------+
|            0 | ADD    | Thing1 |
|            1 | DEL    | Thing1 |
|            2 | ADD    | Thing2 |
+--------------+--------+--------+`

Each of my processes keeps track of the last sequence number it read. Then on an interval it issues a `Scan` against the table with `ExclusiveStartKey` set to that sequence number. I assumed this would result in reading everything after that sequence, but instead I am seeing inconsistent results.

For example, given the table above, if I do a `Scan(ExclusiveStartKey=1)`, I get zero results when I am expecting to see the 3rd row (`seq=2`).

I have a feeling it has to do with the internal hashing DynamoDB uses to partition the items and that I am misusing the `ExclusiveStartKey` option.

Is this the wrong tool for the job?

Alternatively, each process could issue a `Query` for `seq+1` on each interval (looping if anything was found), which would result in the same ReadThroughput, but would require `N` API calls instead of `N/1MB` I would get with a `Scan`.

Comment: Are you complying with the correct syntax of Scan? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_RequestSyntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a DynamoDB Scan operation, it does not seem to proceed sorted by the hash key. So using `ExclusiveStartKey` does not allow you to get an arbitrary page of keys.

For this example table with the Sequence ID, what I want can be accomplished with a Kinesis stream.